# Proper way to get errno value out of PathError

Tags: go, error-handling

I'm trying to determine whether an `os.PathError` is due to an `EINVAL` or `ENOENT`. How do I correctly make that determination?

```
    res, err := os.Readlink(fpath)

    if err, ok := err.(*os.PathError); ok {
        if err.Err == os.ErrInvalid {
            // This path here. What's the correct check?
            return fpath
        }
        log.Printf("ResolveLinks error: %s", err)
        return ""
    }
    log.Printf("Resolved: %s to %s", fpath, res)
    return res
```

If `fpath` points to a regular file instead of a symlink, readlink should produce `EINVAL`, but my `err.Err == os.ErrInvalid` check fails and the following is logged:

`2019/03/28 12:04:42 ResolveLinks error: readlink foo: invalid argument`

I'm supposed to unpack the PathError, but then what? Compare the error string?

I notice that the os module has certain functions to match error types, like [`os.IsNotExist`](https://golang.org/src/os/error.go?s=2154:2185#L65), but I don't see one for all possible error codes.

Answer (score 1):

The `err.Err` is of type `syscall.Errno` and this is integer type that you can convert to int. Running this code on Ubuntu produces error code 22:

```
    if serr, ok := err.Err.(syscall.Errno); ok {
        fmt.Println(int(serr))
    }
```

Bear in mind I do not know if this kind of check is cross platform or not.

if you just want to check file is symlink you can use [Lstat](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Lstat) to get `FileInfo` struct and do the check:

```
fi.Mode() & os.ModeSymlink != 0
```

Comment: Thanks. The error objects appear to be defined as global constants inside the `syscall` module, so simply doing `err.Err == syscall.EINVAL` works and avoids the extra type inference. Thanks for the tip for checking file types, but I'd rather do a single system call and perform error checking there, it also reduces the chances of race conditions where the file changes between the two calls (albeit slim).

Comment: Yeah, this is better than checking int values :D

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the error's string will allow to match on the error type, but I'm not confident (at all) this works across platforms or even locales.

```
if err, ok := err.(*os.PathError); ok {

    //EINVAL
    if err.Err.Error() == "invalid argument" {
        …

    // - OR - 

    //ENOENT
    if err.Err.Error() == "no such file or directory" {
       …
}
```